# Training sentence transformers with MultipleNegativesRankingLoss

Tags: python, machine-learning, loss-function, sentence-transformers

I have to fine tune a `sentence-transformers` model with only positive data. Because of that, I want to use MNR Loss.

I can run this toy example from `sentence-transformers`, and it all works fine:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, InputExample, losses
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

#Define the model. Either from scratch of by loading a pre-trained model
model = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')

#Define your train examples. You need more than just two examples...
train_examples = [InputExample(texts=['My first sentence', 'My second sentence'], label=0.8),
    InputExample(texts=['Another pair', 'Unrelated sentence'], label=0.3)]

#Define your train dataset, the dataloader and the train loss
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_examples, shuffle=True, batch_size=16)
train_loss = losses.CosineSimilarityLoss(model)

#Tune the model
model.fit(train_objectives=[(loader, train_loss)], epochs=10, warmup_steps=100)
```

[image]
Once I try to adapt this toy example to the problem I need to solve, following the strategy present [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-tuning-sentence-transformers-with-mnr-loss-cd6a26685b81), the training just hangs:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, InputExample, losses
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

#Define the model. Either from scratch of by loading a pre-trained model
model = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')

#Define your train examples. You need more than just two examples...
train_examples = [InputExample(texts=['My first sentence', 'My second sentence']),
    InputExample(texts=['Another pair', 'Unrelated sentence'])]

#Define your train dataset, the dataloader and the train loss
train_loss = losses.MultipleNegativesRankingLoss(model)
train_dataloader = sentence_transformers.datasets.NoDuplicatesDataLoader(train_examples, batch_size=16)

#Tune the model
model.fit(train_objectives=[(loader, train_loss)], epochs=10, warmup_steps=100)
```

[image]

It seems the issue is related to my data loader or loss (or both), but so far I haven't figure it out what exactly is the issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the only problem you're having but in both of your code samples you define `train_dataloader` but in the `model.fit` call you use `loader` instead of `train_dataloader`.